# How do I add a square button with a '+' on it to uinavigationbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Like the right button shown in this image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Q61.jpg
Is it a default button provided by apple?
If yes then how do I add it to the navigationBar?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to accept some questions so that people will want to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
  target:self
  action:@selector(myCallback:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that `[+]` button is a default button, provided by Apple. It is the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` identifier.

Here's some code to get it working:

```
// Create the Add button

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
target:self
action:@selector(someMethod)];

// Display it

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

//  Release the button

[addButton release];
```

You will need to define `someMethod`, so your program has code to run when the button is tapped.